# link several powerline networks using wireless?

Tags: routing, wireless, lan, bridge

```
|---------|          |---------|          |---------|     |---------|  
|         |          |         |          |         |     |         |
| PLCnet1 | <-WIFI-> | PLCnet2 | <-WIFI-> | PLCnet3 | ... | PLCnetN |
|---------|          |---------|          |---------|     |---------|
```

**Problem**

I want to link several power line communication (PLC) networks together using wireless comm, forming one large cohesive network sharing the same subnet.  *See above text art.*

Each PLCnet above is a network segment consisting of several nodes. Let's say there are 8 nodes in each segment. Each node is a computer hooked up to a PLC adapter. Each PLCnetwork is independent. I want to create wireless bridges between each independent PLCnetwork so that one large network is formed with all nodes operating on the same subnet; so that the nodes at PLCnetwork1 can communicate with then nodes at PLCnetworkN. Is this possible?  If so, what type of device, in what configuration?

Also, would it be possible to use a DHCP server at PLCnet1 to assign IP addresses to nodes in PLCnetN?

Thank you for your help.

**Constraints:**

- Each PLC network operates on independent electrical wiring.  Each segement is able to communicate using PLC adapters, but cannot use PLC to communicate with other segments.
- Physical connection between PLC networks using Cat5 cabling is not ideal and may not be feasable.

Comment: Questions about product or resource recommendations are off topic. You could ask this question on Hardware Recommendations.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

here you can treat those ***PLCs as normal PCs*** . you may get one ***access point*** (any brand) and make sure its range of coverage can cover all those PLCs . or may you use more than one access point .regarding the ***DHCP*** ,sure you can configure this access point to provide DHCP for those PLCs .all PLC will get iPs from the access point in same range so they can communicate each other.

Answer (score 1):

This question leads to some rather opinion-based answers, which is off-topic. I will try to keep this as general as possible.

Yes, it is possible to do this. There are several way to accomplish what you are asking. You could use Wi-Fi, you could create pseudo data closets and connect them with standard cabling (copper or fiber). There are also specialty radio or laser devices which could connect the separate segments. Basically, you seem to want point-to-point communications from one segment to another. You can do this, but it may not be the best solution, and I doubt very seriously that you will get anything close to the bandwidth or performance you are expecting.

Once you have narrowed down your design, we may be able help with configurations. We can't really design your network for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.    I want to use Wi-Fi to create a point-to-point bridge between the segments.  Can I just buy two access points and configure them to bridge?  If I reduce my description to just two segments, with the DHCP server on segment 1, will I be able to assign IPs to the 2nd segment across the bridge?

Comment: There are wireless bridges and APs that can do what you want, you will need to research which ones can do this. Personally, I think you are going down the wrong path with this, and you will be very disappointed with the results.

Comment: Product and resource recommendations are specifically off-topic. You can ask that in [Hardware Recommendations](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Although technically you might be able to bridge all the different PLC networks together into one big layer-2 domain using WiFi (for which you can indeed then run a single DHCP server), such a setup would probably be very unstable and unreliable as all the broadcast and multicast traffic would have to be duplicated across all those networks.